# How to change DNS server to IP-address from pi-hole?

Tags: dns, raspberrypi

I've installed pi-hole on my raspberry but now I'm having a hard time setting up my pc to use pi-hole as DNS.

What I've done (working in ubuntu 14.04): 
network -> edit network -> IPv4 settings: change to 'Automatic (DHCP) addresses only' and add the IP adress op my PI to DNS-servers.

When I check network -> network information it states it uses my PI as primary DNS-server but still no adds are blocked.

The output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf` results in my old DNS-servers.

How can I make my pc is using my PI as DNS-server please?

(fyi: I cannot change the dns of my router unfortunately)

Comment: you might need to disconnect and reconnect the system to 'refresh' the servers.  Network Manager configs don't update in realtime and you sometimes have to disconnect and reconnect to refresh the configs/settings

Comment: thanks for your input, but even if I disconnect & reconnect to the wifi it's still the same result: no adds are blocked eventough my PI is listed as DNS server.